# Change the text color only on specific numbers in column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, jquery, json-formatting

A little help please! I created a SharePoint list with company contacts and I want in column 'length of service' the numbers 5, 10, 15, 20 etc. years to be marked a different color, for example red.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online modern experience list?

Comment: Please [accept my below response as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you and it will help others with similar question to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint online modern experience list and your "Length Of Service" column is of type "Number", you can use SharePoint column JSON formatting like:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "style": {
        "font-weight": "=if(@currentField == 5 || @currentField == 10 || @currentField == 15 || @currentField == 20, 'bold', '')",
        "color": "=if(@currentField == 5 || @currentField == 10 || @currentField == 15 || @currentField == 20, 'red', '')"
    }
}
```

**OR**:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "[$LengthOfService]",
    "style": {
        "font-weight": "=if([$LengthOfService] == 5 || [$LengthOfService] == 10 || [$LengthOfService] == 15 || [$LengthOfService] == 20, 'bold', '')",
        "color": "=if([$LengthOfService] == 5 || [$LengthOfService] == 10 || [$LengthOfService] == 15 || [$LengthOfService] == 20, 'red', '')"
    }
}
```

Where `[$LengthOfService]` is the internal name of your number column. You can get the exact internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/).

**OR**

If you want to show colored number for all numbers which are multiples of 5, use:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "[$LengthOfService]",
    "style": {
        "font-weight": "=if([$LengthOfService] % 5 == 0, 'bold', '')",
        "color": "=if([$LengthOfService] % 5 == 0, 'red', '')"
    }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

Microsoft official documentation and steps to apply JSON formatting to SharePoint list columns: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)